# How to change a switch state when a button is clicked in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, switch-statement

I am just making a basic app that I can turn on and off switches to tell me if I have homework in a certain class throughout the day.  The problem I am having is the reset button that changes all of the switches to off.  How can I change a switch state in swift with a button?  This is what I had so far:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  HomeworkManager
//
//  Created by Nate Parker on 9/2/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Nathan Parker. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func resetClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBOutlet var spanish: UISwitch
@IBOutlet var algebra: UISwitch
@IBOutlet var amerCult: UISwitch
@IBOutlet var bio: UISwitch
@IBOutlet var col: UISwitch


}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It should just be a matter of using the [`setOn()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISwitch/setOn:animated:) method of the switches:

```
@IBAction func resetClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    spanish.setOn(false, animated: true);
    algebra.setOn(false, animated: true);
    amerCult.setOn(false, animated: true);
    bio.setOn(false, animated: true);
    col.setOn(false, animated: true);
}
```